# Change navbar after user login php

Tags: php, session, authentication, navigation, webshop

I want the "Login/Sign up" button in the navigation bar to change to "My Account" after the user logs in.

The navigation.php file I use for this currently looks like this:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include("check.php");   
?>


<?php 

if ($_SESSION['username']){ ?>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul >
            <li class="navbar-left"><a href="artikelen.html">Men</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-left"><a href="artikelen.html">Women</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-left"><a href="artikelen.html">Kids</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-right"><a href="view_cart.php">Cart (0)</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-right"><a href="inlog.php">My Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<?php } else { ?>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul >
            <li class="navbar-left"><a href="artikelen.html">Men</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-left"><a href="artikelen.html">Women</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-left"><a href="artikelen.html">Kids</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-right"><a href="view_cart.php">Cart (0)</a></li>
            <li class="navbar-right"><a href="inlog.php">Login / Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
<?php }
?>
```

The check.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
session_start();
$user_check=$_SESSION['username'];

$ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$user_check' ");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$login_user=$row['username'];

if(!isset($user_check))
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

If I go to a webpage with this navigation bar I get the following error:

> This webpage has a redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Update your check.php to something like this.

```
$user_check = (isset($_SESSION['username']) && trim($_SESSION['username'])!='')?trim($_SESSION['username']):false;
if(!$user_check) header("Location: index.php");
else{
    $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$user_check' ");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
    $$_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Location header in check.php. You can set the location header after displaying the login form

Answer (score 0):

Try this

navigation.php

```
<?php 
    include("check.php");   
?>


    <?php 

    if ($loginst == 1){ ?>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul >
                <li class="navbar-left"><a href="artikelen.html">Men</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-left"><a href="artikelen.html">Women</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-left"><a href="artikelen.html">Kids</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-right"><a href="view_cart.php">Cart (0)</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-right"><a href="inlog.php">My Account</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <?php } else { ?>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul >
                <li class="navbar-left"><a href="artikelen.html">Men</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-left"><a href="artikelen.html">Women</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-left"><a href="artikelen.html">Kids</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-right"><a href="view_cart.php">Cart (0)</a></li>
                <li class="navbar-right"><a href="inlog.php">Login / Sign Up</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    <?php } ?>
```

check.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
session_start();
$loginst = 0;
if ($_SESSION['username']){ 

$user_check = $_SESSION['username'];

$ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$user_check' ");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$login_user=$row['username'];

if(!empty($login_user)) 
{
   $loginst = 1;
}

}

?>
```